# How to make overflown flexbox element to have width of its children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to ceate table-like grid with scroll using Flexbox. 
[image: no horizontal scroll]

Most of it works okay, but is there any way to force rows to have width of their content when horizontal scrolling is on?

[image: horizontal scroll on]

As you can see, every even row have white background, so it's easy to spot that there's a problem with width.

http://jsbin.com/fedisozafe/embed?html,css,output

```js
$('.tbody').on('scroll', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings().scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});

$('.tbody').perfectScrollbar();

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    $('.tbody')
      .perfectScrollbar('update')
      .siblings()
        .scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});


angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('testController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
            this.n = 5;
            $scope.$watch(() => this.n, () => this.collection = _.range(this.n));
        }
    ]);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.table > * {
    border-top: solid 1px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
}
.thead {
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
.tfoot {
    border-top: solid 1px red;
}
.thead {
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    order: -1;
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
.tbody {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.tfoot {
    flex: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    order: 1;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.tr {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: white;
}
.td,
.th {
    flex: 1 0 60px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.th {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/js/min/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css"/>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
 <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.n" ng-max="100" />
 <div style="display: flex">
  <div style="flex: 1 1 auto">
   <table class="table" style="width: 40vw; height: 40vh">
    <tbody class="tbody" style="height: calc(100% - 60px)">
     <tr class="tr" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.collection" style="min-width: 200px">
      <th class="th">{{item}}</th>
      <th class="td" style="flex-basis: 200px">{{item}}</th>
      <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
      <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
      <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead class="thead">
     <tr class="tr">
      <td class="th">A</td>
      <td class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</td>
      <td class="th">C</td>
      <td class="th">D</td>
      <td class="th">E</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="tfoot">
     <tr class="tr">
      <th class="th">A</th>
      <th class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</th>
      <th class="th">C</th>
      <th class="th">D</th>
      <th class="th">E</th>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 auto">
   <div class="table" style="width: 40vw; height: 40vh">
    <div class="tbody" style="height: calc(100% - 60px)">
    <div class="tr" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.collection">
     <div class="th">{{item}}</div>
     <div class="td" style="flex-basis: 200px">{{item}}</div>
     <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
     <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
     <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thead">
    <div class="tr">
     <div class="th">A</div>
     <div class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</div>
     <div class="th">C</div>
     <div class="th">D</div>
     <div class="th">E</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tfoot">
    <div class="tr">
     <div class="th">A</div>
     <div class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</div>
     <div class="th">C</div>
     <div class="th">D</div>
     <div class="th">E</div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

---

## EDIT 1

It's important that rows calculate their width based on its cells, not the other way round. In an ideal world row would grow when space is available (and allow cells to grow as well), but would not shrink - that's why scrolling is enabled.

I'm aware that there's a possibility it can't be done. I've spent quite some time on it, but I still cling to hope that I'm just not as clever as you guys.

Comment: So you want  each row to conform to the total widths of it's children? Or do you want each "cell" to conform to the widest content in a column? You have a real table and you have a pseudo-div-table. That's to experiment?

Comment: The first. The latter I believe is not possible without javascript or without column-first approach. Or is it? :-)

Comment: The column first-approach would be daunting w/o JS indeed, thank God you have the sensibility to request the former :P Is IE a requirement, sir?

Comment: Nah, browsers only :-)

Comment: Ha! You're all right in my book @m1gu3l 

Answer (score 6):

There were no mistakes, HTML, CSS, and JS (I'll assume Angular and loDash are good to go.) all good. So OP just needed a way to *shrink wrap* the rows. The rows extended in weird looking overflow? There were some changes to the CSS, but they were more for aesthetics and small adjustments. The main style changes are as follows:

```
    .tr {
      display: flex;
      min-width: -moz-fit-content;
      min-width: -webkit-fit-content;
      min-width: fit-content;
      flex: 1 0 20px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```

> [`fit-content`](http://thenewcode.com/975/Little-Big-Using-CSS-fit-content) is an old but little known property still in it's experimental stage. What it basically does is it will make an element wrap it's content in a perfect fit. So if you apply it to a parent element, the parent will be as wide as it's content and it will increase and decrease with the content.

```
- Result: The overflow was gone but `tr` did not extend.
```

> Removed the `flex-direction: column` so it would default to [`flex-direction: row`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/) I figured that a `tr` flowing in a vertical direction would probably stop short and abruptly.

```
- Result: The `tr` extended, but the `td`s and `th`s were not aligned.
```

> [`justify-content: flex-end`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) applied in order to shift the columns to the right recalling the problem was on the right side of the table.

```
- Result: http://jsbin.com/godoqi/3/edit?css,output
```

> [`table-layout: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) was also applied to the table so there's more control over column widths.

```
- Result: See previous result.
```

[**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/godoqi/3/edit?css,output)

**Snippet**

```js
$('.tbody').on('scroll', function(e) {
  $(this).siblings().scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});

$('.tbody').perfectScrollbar();

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
  $('.tbody')
    .perfectScrollbar('update')
    .siblings()
    .scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
});


angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      this.n = 5;
      $scope.$watch(() => this.n, () => this.collection = _.range(this.n));
    }
  ]);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table > * {
  border-top: solid 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
}
.thead {
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
.tfoot {
  border-top: solid 1px red;
}
.thead {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: -1;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
.tbody {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.tfoot {
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  order: 1;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
.tr {
  display: flex;
  min-width: -moz-fit-content;
  min-width: -webkit-fit-content;
  min-width: fit-content;
  flex: 1 0 20px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: white;
}
.td,
.th {
  flex: 0 1 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ng-not-empty {
  text-align: center;
  width: 8ex;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/js/min/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.n" ng-max="100" />
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div style="flex: 1 1 auto">
      <table class="table" style="width: 40vw; height: 40vh">
        <tbody class="tbody" style="height: calc(100% - 60px)">
          <tr class="tr" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.collection" style="min-width: 200px">
            <th class="th">{{item}}</th>
            <th class="td" style="flex-basis: 200px">{{item}}</th>
            <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
            <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
            <th class="td">{{item}}</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <thead class="thead">
          <tr class="tr">
            <td class="th">A</td>
            <td class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</td>
            <td class="th">C</td>
            <td class="th">D</td>
            <td class="th">E</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot class="tfoot">
          <tr class="tr">
            <th class="th">A</th>
            <th class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</th>
            <th class="th">C</th>
            <th class="th">D</th>
            <th class="th">E</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 1 1 auto">
      <div class="table" style="width: 40vw; height: 40vh">
        <div class="tbody" style="height: calc(100% - 60px)">
          <div class="tr" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.collection">
            <div class="th">{{item}}</div>
            <div class="td" style="flex-basis: 200px">{{item}}</div>
            <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
            <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
            <div class="td">{{item}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="thead">
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="th">A</div>
            <div class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</div>
            <div class="th">C</div>
            <div class="th">D</div>
            <div class="th">E</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tfoot">
          <div class="tr">
            <div class="th">A</div>
            <div class="th" style="flex-basis: 200px">B</div>
            <div class="th">C</div>
            <div class="th">D</div>
            <div class="th">E</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 for exploring _fit-content_. It's an answer, yet it's not the answer I'm looking for and here's why:
1) shrinking rows won't really work on small screen or when there's a lot of columns - that's why overflow and scrolling is needed
2) shrinking rows seems to be also the cause of columns not aligning
3) table on the right looks like it's not working at all
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Try changing `fit-content` to `max-content` The table on the right seems to work as the one on the right for me. Do you use a Mac or PC and what browsers are you using? Did you review http://jsbin.com/godoqi/3/edit?css,output ?

Comment: Btw the table on the right cannot be expected to mimic the one on the left unless you assign `display: table/table-cell/table-row` which atm is impossible because every div has a `display: flex` There will always be differences in behavior between those 2 tables because the differences between div and a table, tr, or td.

Comment: Still no cigar. Chrome 49 and Firefox 44 on Windows, you? Try to resize output window to 400px or less - do you have horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to `.tbody`

Comment: I use the one and the same as you do.  When perfect scrollbar is updating on resize you have the siblings of which element scrollLeft? See my last comment.

Comment: tbody's scrollLeft is synced with thead and tfoot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105507/discussion-between-zer00ne-and-m1gu3l).